# Get content of Current Button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

```
<Button Name="btn1" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
<Button Name="btn2" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

How do i get the content of the current button with just one function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button obj = (Button)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(obj.Content.ToString());
}
```